# React Navigation deep link and Splash screen useEffect conflicting causing double navigation behavior

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I'm working on our deeplinking behavior. We currently use react-navigation deeplinking to handle income url deeplink requests. However, we also have a hook that redirects a user from the splash screen once the state has loaded. This causes a weird double redirect.

Splash screen useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAppReadyToRedirect) {
      if (!user) {
        // Case 1: User is logged out
        resetToRootScreen(RootScreen.Auth); // notes these are all just callbacks around navigationRef calls
      } else if (user.isAnonymous) {
        // Case 2: User is anonymous
        redirectAnonymousUser();
      } else {
        // Case 3: User has linked their email
        resetToRootScreen(RootScreen.HomeTabs);
      }
    }
```

and linking config:

```
export const linkingConfig = {
  prefixes: [DEEP_LINK_SCHEME],

  subscribe(listener: any) {
    const branchUnsubscribe = branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
      if (error) {
        logError(error);
        return;
      }
      if (params) {
        const url = params.$canonical_url;
        if (url) {
          listener(url);
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      // Clean up the event listeners
      branchUnsubscribe();
    };
  },
  config: {
    screens: {
        // screens
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Is there a way to prevent the useEffect from running if the deep link redirect is already happening?

Comment: Sure, you just have to make your isAppReadyToRedirect take into account whether the deeplink handler has run yet. Put isAppReadyToRedirect in global state or a Context, initialize as false, and pass the redirect handler a function to set the context value. Or move the linking config inside the context. Lots of ways it could be done